# Getting checked exception while automating a web application in Firefox using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, firefox, exception, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class shopComLogin {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{
   //Launch a Firefox Browser
   WebDriver window=new FirefoxDriver();
   //Navigating to Shop.com
   try{
   window.get("http://www.shop.com/");
   Thread.sleep(4000);
   window.findElement((By.xpath(".//*[@id='global-redirects']/div[2]/a[1]/div[1]/div[1]"))).click();
   Thread.sleep(2000);
   WebElement wb=window.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='super-header-menu']/div[1]/a"));
   wb.click();
   Thread.sleep(4000);
   String enteredEmailId="shantanunandann@gmail.com";
   window.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='sign_in_email_textfield']")).sendKeys(enteredEmailId);
   window.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='no_account_radio_button']")).click();
   window.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='signin_button']")).click();
   Thread.sleep(2000);
   String actualEmailId=window.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='sign_in_email_textfield']")).getText();
   if(enteredEmailId.equalsIgnoreCase(actualEmailId)){
       System.out.println("Same email id "+ actualEmailId);
      }//if closed
      else{
     System.out.println("Email id field value does't match");  
     window.close();
   }//else closed
  }//try close
   catch(InterruptedException interrupt){
       interrupt.printStackTrace();
  }//catch close
 }//main closed
}//class closed

Exception which i am getting for this program is-
 Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Unable to bind to locking port 7054 within 45000 ms
 Build info: version: '2.39.0', revision: 'ff23eac', time: '2013-12-16 16:12:12'
System info: host: 'omega-d52b83806', ip: '10.0.0.7', os.name: 'Windows XP', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '5.1', java.version: '1.7.0_45'
  Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
at org.openqa.selenium.internal.SocketLock.lock(SocketLock.java:98)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:84)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:250)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:110)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:197)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:190)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:186)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:99)
at shopComLogin.main(shopComLogin.java:7)
```

I run this program today. For the first 2 execution i was getting the desired output excluding the if block. On the 4th run the program starts giving me exception as mentioned in the code above. Don't know why i am getting this and how to fix it.

Secondly in my first 2 executions the code written inside the if block is not executing at all i.e, i am not getting the desired output nor any exception or error. Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: Hi Shantanu, one of the reason for the exception might be the firefox process might not be closed before you execute the script for the second time. For the 2nd problem remove the . in the xpath. Hope this solves the issue. Happy coding.

Comment: @vijay Hi Vijay, You was right in the backgroung firefox was running. I killed it in task manger and now its working. But for the second problem i am not getting any string value for actualEmailId. You have any idea?

Comment: My name is Vinay :) Can you share the html for the email id. Will let you know the reason why it is not identified.

Comment: @vinay Sorry vinay for putting wrong name(Vijay is my frnd thats why u did that silly mistak). How to send html of emailid? Are u talking about the web page from where i am trying to get the data? Link for that page is - https://www.shop.com/cc.class/cc?main=myaccount&act=login&ccsyn=260

Comment: In the if block instead of getText() use getAttribute("value"). If you want to get the text from editBox then you should use this and not getText. Also I see there is ID for all the fields. Use ID instead of xpath. Reserve xpath only for dynamic scenarios.

Comment: @Vinay what i should pass as argument in getAttribute("");

Comment: @Vinay Thanks for your help. I figured out how to use getAttribute("value") and now i am getting the expected output.

Comment: If you have got the solution then please upvote the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I read some where & it worked for me below thing.

Its because of the more than one javaw.exe is running in the background. Kill those processes and give a try.

https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/taskman_end_process.mspx?mfr=true